# How to resolve encoding errors in python geoprocessing?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I have a simple python script that reads a string from a text file and inserts it into an Oracle database.

When I run the script with Eclipse using Pydev plugin I get no error and the message is inserted into database.

However, when I run the script using an ArcGIS geoprocessing service (using a toolbox), I get the following error in the logs, and no insertion is performed into database:

```
[06/09/2013-10:30:39.380] ERROR - APPLICATION <module>(<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u"INSERT INTO APPLI.ALERT (ID_ALERT,MESSAGE,TYPE_ALERT) values(1617.0,q'[Les coordonn\xe9es ne sont pas correctes\n]',3)", 94, 95, 'ordinal not in range(128)'))
```

The code is the following:

```
try:
    msg=open("myFile.log", 'r')
    a=msg.read(20) 
    strInsert = "INSERT INTO  APPLI.ALERT(ID_ALERT,MESSAGE,TYPE_ALERT) values(1625.0,'"+a.replace('\"','').decode('utf-8')+"',3)"
    logger_module.debug(str(strInsert))
    SdeExecuteSQL(CONNEXION_FILE,strInsert )
except:
    python_error_handler()
```

When I open myFile.log with Notepad++ the encoding is ANSI as UTF-8.

Do you have any hint?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:
The problem comes from `logger_module.debug(str(strInsert))`
I deleted `str()` and everything runs correctly now with `logger_module.debug(strInsert)`

Do you have any idea why it worked in Eclipse but not in ArcGIS Server?